# On the pro*C program, Why is the CLOSE CURSOR not performed in the child-process?

Tags: c, oracle, fork, oracle-pro-c

In summary...

```
int main() {       
                   
    pid_t childPid;
        
    EXEC SQL CONNECT :username IDENTIFIED BY :password;     
    for (;;)
    {
        childPid = fork();
        
        if(childPid > 0)
        {   // parent process
            ...
            ...
            ...                        
        }
        else if(childPid == 0)
        {  // chiled process
            EXEC SQL DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR
             SELECT empno, ename, sal FROM emp;
     
            for (;;)
            {
               EXEC SQL OPEN c1;
               EXEC SQL FETCH c1 INTO :emp_rec;
      
               if(sqlca.sqlcode == 1403)
               {
                   EXEC SQL CLOSE c1;
                   EXEC SQL COMMIT WORK RELEASE;
                   break;
               }
               ...
               ...
               //A function that sends results to the Client program.
               SendPacketTOClient(fd,size);
            }
            EXEC SQL COMMIT WORK;
            exit(0);
        }
        else {  // fork Fail
            perror("fork Fail! \n");
            return -1;
        }
        
        sleep(60);            
    }
    retun 0;
}
```

As above, DB CONNECT is performed in the parent process and forks is performed every minute, and the child process ends with exit (0) after inquiry (DECLARE->OPEN->FETCH->CLOSE).
There was no problem because it was processed until FETCH. But if CLOSE is not working properly, there was an ORA-01000: maximum open response error later.
When I actually checked, the child process was created and it didn't close when it was terminated after finishing work.

After Serch, I found out that it was a problem because the Servie Process was one, so I solved it by branching the parent process and the child process DB connection.

I solved it, but I want to know the principle, so I leave a question.
May I know why DECLARE, OPEN, and FETCH are executed, but COLSE is not executed?

Thanks.

Comment: From the code you posted (which has an error as if(sqlca.sqlcode==1403 is not closed), you are only fetching one row from the cursor, and then checking if you got to the end to close it, then you open it again and fetch. So, if your cursor does return rows, you are not closing it before the next open, and you end up having lots of open cursors. And as all your forked processes use the same connection, so all the cursors they open contribute to the same max, you get there very quickly.

Comment: @gsalen  Thank you for your answer.
As you said, the error was corrected.

And I haven't solved the problem yet.
The child process takes less than 10 seconds to survive.
The sleep time of the parent process is 1 minute.So, prior to CURSOR OPEN of the next child process, FETCH is completed and the child process is terminated.
In this case, the sqlcode value after CURSOR CLOSE is 0 (normal)
Nevertheless, I wonder why the cursor does not close.

Comment: Try to print sqlcode after the fetch, and see what you get. Probably bot 1403.

Answer (score -1):

Add "EXEC SQL FREE :c1;" Statement.
This will free the open cursors.
Also add "EXEC SQL ALLOCATE :c1;" Statement after declaring the cursor.